# Applying OncePerRequestFilter based on Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop

I wanted to write a Annotation based api which can record and request and response in my library.
Basically the plan was if a developer did something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/todo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@CustomCopy
public void createNewTodo() {
```

I would copy the request and response and dump to a database. I had started to use the `HandlerInterceptorAdaptor` with `afterComplete` but that did not lead anywhere since I cannot copy the response as it is flushed out by that time afterComplete is invoked.

Next I was planning to use the `OncePerRequestFilter` method. Basically use this as the template.

I just could not figure out:

- How can I connect the Annotation with my filter ?
- If there is another method where I can use the Annotation but also use the request and response body.
- I was planning to use to look into AOP but still have not figured it out.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using AOP you can do it like this:

**dependency**:

```
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:{version}'
```

Create Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomCopy {

}
```

Save request response:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SaveRequestResponse {
    @Around("@annotation(CustomCopy)")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        //Request build
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper request = getWrapper(joinPoint);
        StringBuilder apiLog = new StringBuilder();
        apiLog.append("Rest API: ").append(request.getRequestURL().toString()).append("\n");
        apiLog.append("Body:").append(getRequestBody(request)).append("\n");

        for (String header : Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames())) {
            apiLog.append(header).append(":").append(request.getHeader(header))
                    .append("\n");
        }
        //Request build end

        //method called
        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

        //after method called response
        String response = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(proceed);
        //save apiLog(Full request) && response
        return proceed;
    }
    private String getRequestBody(final ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper) {
        String payload = null;
        if (wrapper != null) {
            byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (buf.length > 0) {
                try {
                    int maxLength = buf.length > 500 ? 500 : buf.length;
                    payload = new String(buf, 0, maxLength,
                            wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    logger.error("UnsupportedEncoding.", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return payload;
    }
    private ContentCachingRequestWrapper getWrapper(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper request = null;
        for (Object arg : args) {
            if (arg instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper) {
                request = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) arg;
                break;
            }
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

Now use this `@CustomCopy` annotation in controller method.